# Wordpress - Image is blurry in single product page when page is loaded

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, blurry

I have an issue with images in WordPress/Woocommerce.

All my images are fine, except for the single product image is blurry when I load the page for the first time. After a browser refresh, the image looks sharp. Even if I open the console (F12), the images are fine after I close it. The images look good when I zoom on them. For now, the only way to make the image look good is to refresh the browser.

I have tried to modify the image size in Media settings, I have checked my CSS, I tried to overwrite the width of the image, cleared the cache, all lazy loading plugins are disabled.

Do you have any other solutions to help me to fix this issue?

Here's a link to see what is the issue:
https://www.labtag.com/shop/product/cab-thermal-transfer-direct-thermal-desktop-printer-mach1-2/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your images for regular size is smaller than image used for zoom. If you look at html code this image is user for regular in `<a>` tag:

`https://cdn.labtag.com/wp-content/uploads/mach1_800_neu__79290.1492715013.1280.1280-416x378.jpg`

This image is much smaller than image that have used for zoom:

`https://cdn.labtag.com/wp-content/uploads/mach1_800_neu__79290.1492715013.1280.1280.jpg`

Your regular image size is thumbnailed version, You should change your code show original version of image there.